# SQL many-to-many relationship with members of same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an application that tracks siblings. There is a "Members" table. That's it for now. Members can be "Siblings" of one another. I want to somehow track relationships between different members of the "Members" table. I tried doing it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE members (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT NOT NULL, 
    last_name TEXT NOT NULL 
); 

CREATE TABLE siblings (
    member_one_id INTEGER REFERENCES members (id), 
    member_two_id INTEGER REFERENCES members (id), 
    PRIMARY KEY (member_one_id, member_two_id)
);
```

But I have no idea how to query this structure. I tried this

```
SELECT * FROM members 
INNER JOIN siblings 
ON members.id = siblings.member_one_id OR members.id = siblings.member_two_id 
INNER JOIN members 
ON members.id = siblings.member_one_id OR members.id = sibling.member_two_id;
```

and I keep getting the error:

```
ERROR:  table name "members" specified more than once
```

Is there a way to both store this type of relationship and query it effectively? My SQL knowledge gets thinner with more complex structures like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use table aliases like this:

```
SELECT * FROM members one
INNER JOIN siblings 
ON one.id = siblings.member_one_id OR one.id = siblings.member_two_id 
INNER JOIN members two
ON two.id = siblings.member_one_id OR two.id = sibling.member_two_id
```

Comment: This works pretty well! Except I'm getting members matching themselves which is not ideal

Answer (score 0):

Table structure looks good. You can use a CTE to traverse relationship(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html)